# How to use an Angular 2x component into ag-grid noRowsTemplate value

Tags: html, css, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to use an Angular component with a few properties inside the ag-grid *noRowsTemplate* property. Something similar to this:

```
noRowsTemplate="<app-empty-state desc="No Rows"></app-empty-state>"
```

This does not work, because the *noRowsTemplate* property only accepts plain old HTML. I was wondering if in Angular 2x there's something similar to a function that you can "precompile" a compoment and return flat HTML and CSS that I can set to the *noRowsTemplate* property.
Can you please help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: I ended up adding an *ngIf and displaying a custom empty state, out off ag-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there no way to add an angular component in accordance with official documentation.

But you can simply add markup. Give needed classes, add these classes in the main CSS file.
And style it as you want.

````
  `<div class="overlayNoRowsTemplate">
     <span style="padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #444; background: lightgoldenrodyellow;">
       This is a custom \'no rows\' overlay
     </span>
</div>`;```

.overlayNoRowsTemplate {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
````

Planker:https://plnkr.co/edit/yEajXlR7Cm6wfKKp